how to integrate the Spring xml and Confluent kafka consumer in legacy spring application
how to integrate the Spring xml and Confluent kafka consumer in legacy spring application
to give some background
Current Application - Spring xml Configuration  ( No Spring Boot )
We want to integrate the kafka consumer to read the data from the confluent kafka producer
and we have to write the code in spring xml based configuration to read the messages how to
implement this if any body has any idea please revert would be helpful
expecting that spring configuration xml can create a consumer and read the data in java application

any body answers

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
